# Datastax Astra : error fetching metadata information using secure bundle

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cqlsh, datastax-astra

My goal is to use a Secure Connect Bundle to connect to my database on Astra. However, I'm getting This error (underlined in blue):

[image]

---

First I went to my server (Celestia) and went to the connect tab to download the bundle.
[image]

---

Afterwards, I followed the instruction:[image]

Since I am on windows i used "type nul" to create the file instead of touch connect-database.js.

---

I modified the connect-database.js file as per the instructions.
[image]
However, as mentioned above when I try to run the code :`node connect-database.js`
I get a NoHostAvailableError.

Comment: Please don't post images of code or error messages.  The actual text (formatted, of course) is much better for search and for helping to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Following the instructions - I am able to connect without issue - the only difference being that I am using OSX and not windows.

Double check that you have not set the database to 'Restrict Public Access', you would need to have your IP in the allow list to make a connection.